# React Router Redirected too many times

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I have the following Router.jsx, and what I want to accomplish is to have any wildcard redirect back to root level (Home).

i.e. http://xxxxxxx.com/randomPath should redirect to -> http://xxxxxxx.com/

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/faq" component={Faq} />
    <Route path="/more" component={Faq} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
    <Route path="/legal" component={Legal} />
    <Route path="/ugc" component={Ugc} />
    <Route path="/pricing" component={Pricing} />

    <Redirect from="*" to='/' />
  </Switch>
```

However, when testing this out, I'm getting: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Your help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: is the Home component redirecting to something like `/home/` instead of `/home`?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd just set `<Redirect to="/" />` (no extra parameters), and it works fine.